# Matching terms disjunction

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch, and finding the query DSL quite unwieldy. I am trying to return all documents that match a number of values for either 2 different fields. This is how I constructed the query, but it does not work:

```
POST myindex/type/_search
{
   "query": {
       "filtered": {
          "filter": {
              "terms": {
                 "ref": ["1431007639", "1431007633"],
                 "advertiserName": ["Ad1", "ad2"]
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

If it worked, this should return all documents whose ref field is either 1431007639 or 1431007633, and (union) all the documents whose advertiserName is either Ad1 or Ad2.

If I leave out one of the conditions, the result is correct for the single condition. When I mix in the two conditions in this way, the number of documents returned is not right.

Can someone who hgets this help me create a simple OR query?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple terms filters in the same `terms` filter. Try this one:

```
POST myindex/type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "terms" : {
                                "ref": ["1431007639", "1431007633"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms" : {
                                "advertiserName": ["Ad1", "ad2"]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see more at this in the [ES bool filter docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html).